# Can't Change Search Box Width Or Position For DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a `DataTable` which i have been styling/setting up and i'm almost there but i just cant figure out the last few styling things i'm after for the `search` `input`

- Left align the input
- Make field wider
- Set focus on load
- Make field same size as other fields on site

I have the following code i'm using

**JQuery**

```
$('#dialPlanListTable').dataTable({
    "ordering": true,               // Allows ordering
    "searching": true,              // Searchbox
    "paging": true,                 // Pagination
    "info": false,                  // Shows 'Showing X of X' information
    "pagingType": 'simple_numbers', // Shows Previous, page numbers & next buttons only
    "pageLength": 10,               // Defaults number of rows to display in table
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": 'dialPlanButtons',
            "searchable": false,    // Stops search in the fields 
            "sorting": false,       // Stops sorting
            "orderable": false      // Stops ordering
        }
    ],
    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // Positions table elements
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]], // Sets up the amount of records to display
    "language": {
        "search": "_INPUT_",            // Removes the 'Search' field label
        "searchPlaceholder": "Search"   // Placeholder for the search box
    }
});
```

**Current look**
[image]

**HTML Returned/Rendered**

```
<div class="top">
    <div id="dialPlanListTable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
        <label>
            <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="dialPlanListTable">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the search box is smaller than the one above (which will be removed once this one is styled) and is not left to the table.  I have looked at the https://datatables.net/ site and cant find the last few things i need.

I'd prefer NOT to have to update my `.css` as i don't want to affect the reset of the site, just this page only so dont mind using `JQuery` to add styling. also the `input` is sat inside the `label` as shown in the `HTML` above

Comment: please add a code snippet for the same here to replicate.

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel Not sure what your after, i've given all details, screenshots of how it looks and `HTML` rendered for the search field, nothing more i can provide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not what i was hoping for but resolved by doing the below

```
    $('#dialPlanListTable').dataTable({
        "ordering": true,               // Allows ordering
        "searching": true,              // Searchbox
        "paging": true,                 // Pagination
        "info": false,                  // Shows 'Showing X of X' information
        "pagingType": 'simple_numbers', // Shows Previous, page numbers & next buttons only
        "pageLength": 10,               // Defaults number of rows to display in table
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": 'dialPlanButtons',
                "searchable": false,    // Stops search in the fields 
                "sorting": false,       // Stops sorting
                "orderable": false      // Stops ordering
            }
        ],
        "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // Positions table elements
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]], // Sets up the amount of records to display
        "language": {
            "search": "_INPUT_",            // Removes the 'Search' field label
            "searchPlaceholder": "Search"   // Placeholder for the search box
        },
        "search": {
            "addClass": 'form-control input-lg col-xs-12'
        },
        "fnDrawCallback":function(){
            $("input[type='search']").attr("id", "searchBox");
            $('#dialPlanListTable').css('cssText', "margin-top: 0px !important;");
            $("select[name='dialPlanListTable_length'], #searchBox").removeClass("input-sm");
            $('#searchBox').css("width", "300px").focus();
            $('#dialPlanListTable_filter').removeClass('dataTables_filter');
        }
    });
```

So got the look i was going for
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You can create a custom textbox (*in this case you have full control of styling* ) in the top of the table and hide the default text box.

```
  <p>
      <input type="text" id="mySearchText" placeholder="Search...">
      <button id="mySearchButton">Search</button>
   </p>


  var table =  $('#dialPlanListTable').dataTable({
        "ordering": true,               // Allows ordering
        "searching": false,              // Searchbox
        "paging": true,                 // Pagination
        "info": false,                  // Shows 'Showing X of X' information
        "pagingType": 'simple_numbers', // Shows Previous, page numbers & next buttons only
        "pageLength": 10,               // Defaults number of rows to display in table
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": 'dialPlanButtons',
                "searchable": false,    // Stops search in the fields 
                "sorting": false,       // Stops sorting
                "orderable": false      // Stops ordering
            }
        ],
        "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // Positions table elements
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]], // Sets up the amount of records to display
        "language": {
            "search": "_INPUT_",            // Removes the 'Search' field label
            "searchPlaceholder": "Search"   // Placeholder for the search box
        }
    });
 $('#mySearchButton').on( 'keyup click', function () {
    table.search($('#mySearchText').val()).draw();
  } );
```

**Solution 2**

based on their documentation http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html you can add a custom class to the search box container( for example myCustomClass)

```
   "dom": '<"myCustomClass"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // Positions table elements
```

You can customize the look of the search box by adding styles on that class

```
.myCustomClass{
background-color:red    
}
```

Comment: I want to keep and use all `dataTable` fubctionality

Comment: yes you can keep default functionality ( see solution 2)